# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'raj' in 'field list' at sun.reflect

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm making a simple phone book diary, so here is my database schema:

```
create database if not exists Rajendra;

use Rajendra;

create table if not exists family(name varchar(50), mobile varchar(50));

select * from family;
```

Now, i'm inserting values from `input dialog boxes` but that's giving me this kind of errors:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'raj' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2819)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at phonebook.MainProgram$2.actionPerformed(MainProgram.java:76)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And here is my code for java:

```
jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
                try{
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Rajendra", "root", "1234");
                    Statement st=con.createStatement();
                    st.executeUpdate("INSERT into family(name, mobile)"
                            +"values("+name+", "+num+")");
                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to add quotes arround the strings.

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT into family(name, mobile)"
                            +"values('"+name+"', '"+num+"')");
```

A better Solution is to learn about prepared statement. It prevent sql-injection and makes the statement better readable.

Comment: But can you tell me, why do we use here ' ' into this??

Comment: @RajendraArora bacause you work with char datatype in sql. In this case there must be quotes arround the values. That is SQL requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this :

```
Statement st=con.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("INSERT into family(name, mobile) values("+name+", "+num+")");
```

Why dont you try something like this

```
PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO family(name, mobile) VALUES(?,?)");
st.setString(1,name);
st.setString(2,num);
st.executeUpdate();
```

**Advantages** of `PreparedStatement`

1. Parameterized query is a good way to avoid SQL Injection
2. Precompilation and DB-side caching of the SQL statement leads to overall faster execution.

Comment: This is a better answer. Fewer errors and no chance of sql injection

Answer (score 0):

You have to add double quote in the executeUpdate statement so that mysql will consider it as String input like this:

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT into family(name, mobile)"
                            +"values('"+name+"', '"+num+"')");
```